# Add many frameworks to Xcode at once

Tags: xcode

When I want to install a 3rd party library, it requires me to add many frameworks (in targets ->Build Phases -> Link Binary With Libraries)

Now I can add framework one by one using plus button. But how can I add many libraries at once so I don't need to click the plus button again and again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just select click on multiple frameworks listed by holding down the cmd key on your keyboard. If you want to select the range of frameworks simply click over 1st framework in range hold down the shift key and click over the last framework in range.

Please find the solution in screenshot:

[image]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQEoz.png

[image]

Comment: It works! Thanks! One more question, can I add many frameworks at once and use the search bar (that under "Choose frameworks and libraries to add:") at the same time?

Comment: Happy to help :). Yes you can add using search bar but your search keyword should not filter out the needed framework they must be listed as search result. If they are all listed just select them using `Shift` or `cmd` key.